# Set php variable in href but don't show it in url

Tags: php

I have a link

```
<p><a href="?action=course_list">List Courses</a></p>
```

in a view, and an $action variable in a controller that tests the value of the 
$action then displays the appropriate view.

When I press the ahref link I dont want the variable to show in the URL, It shows
http://localhost/project/?action=course_list

I want the url to say the name of the view that is loaded in the controller
or http://localhost/project/course_list

Comment: A simple way around this is to replace the href you have with "javascript:void(0)" and then add an event listener for this link with a location.href = 'your_href'; inside the listener function

Comment: R u using codignitor ??

Comment: No, just regular php

Comment: If you put a non-semantic url in the `href` tag, then that is exactly what is going to show up in the address bar unless you're doing some type of rewriting in `.htaccess`.

Comment: About which controller are you talking about, are you using some kind of framework?